# Positioning and event issues with a javascript slider

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I would like to integrate a slider in javascript but I have some troubles :

- The width and height values of elements (such as `#wrapper`, `#slider`) should be defined in the javascript file but instead they are set to 0.
- Events such as next and previous buttons for slides are not working.

I tried to run this slider in a custom html page and it works very well.

If you want to see what's happening on the browser : https://ibb.co/wgp8Ptn

Thanks a lot !

```js
slider();
window.onresize = function() {
  // slider();
}

function slider() {
  // On récupère tous les id et classes
  var slideWidth = 1200;
  var slideHeight = 800;
  var slideDelay = 1000;
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  var slide = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
  var slideCount = slide.length; // On récupère le nombre de slide
  // console.log(slider.clientWidth); Récupère la largeur de la div slider

  if (slider.clientWidth < slideWidth) {
    slideHeight = slider.clientWidth / slideWidth * slideHeight;
    // console.log(slideHeight);
    slideWidth = slider.clientWidth;
  }

  slider.style.width = slideWidth + "px"; // On définit la width du slider
  slider.style.height = slideHeight + "px"; // On définit la height du slider

  // On définit le style du wrapper
  wrapper.style.width = slideWidth * slideCount + "px";
  wrapper.style.height = slideHeight + "px";
  wrapper.style.marginLeft = 0;

  // Vignettes (li)
  var groupBtn = document.createElement("ul");
  groupBtn.id = "group-btn";
  slider.appendChild(groupBtn);

  // On définit la taille de chaque slide
  for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
    slide[i].style.width = slideWidth + "px";
    slide[i].style.height = slideHeight + "px";
    var slideBtn = document.createElement("li");
    slideBtn.classList.add("btn-slide");
    slideBtn.id = "btn-" + i;
    groupBtn.appendChild(slideBtn);
    slideLi(i);
  }

  // On crée l'élément qui viendra acceuillir la flèche NEXT
  var nextButton = document.createElement("div");
  nextButton.id = "next-button";
  slider.appendChild(nextButton);
  nextButton.style.top = (slideHeight - 100) / 2 + "px";

  nextButton.onclick = function() {
    slideNext();
  }

  // On crée l'élément qui viendra acceuillir la flèche PREVIOUS
  var previousButton = document.createElement("div");
  previousButton.id = "previous-button";
  slider.appendChild(previousButton);
  previousButton.style.top = (slideHeight - 100) / 2 + "px";

  previousButton.onclick = function() {
    slidePrevious();
  }

  // On crée une fonction pour passer à l'image suivante
  function slideNext() {
    var oldMarginLeft = wrapper.style.marginLeft; // On récupère (l'ancienne) marge du wrapper
    oldMarginLeft = Number(oldMarginLeft.replace("px", "")); // On le convertit en nombre et on enlève le 'px'
    if (oldMarginLeft == -(slideCount - 1) * slideWidth) // - (6 - 1) * 1200 = 6000
    {
      wrapper.style.marginLeft = 0; // On remet la marginLeft à 0 (pour retourner au début)
    } else {
      wrapper.style.marginLeft = oldMarginLeft - slideWidth + "px"; // On enlève 1200px (slideWidth) au marginLeft du wrapper
    }
    slideActif();
  }

  function slidePrevious() {
    var oldMarginLeft = wrapper.style.marginLeft; // On récupère (l'ancienne) marge du wrapper
    oldMarginLeft = Number(oldMarginLeft.replace("px", "")); // On le convertit en nombre et on enlève le 'px'
    if (oldMarginLeft == 0) {
      wrapper.style.marginLeft = -(slideCount - 1) * slideWidth + "px";
    } else {
      wrapper.style.marginLeft = oldMarginLeft + slideWidth + "px"; // On enlève 1200px (slideWidth) au marginLeft du wrapper
    }
    slideActif();
  }

  // Permet de changer d'image (marge) lorsqu'on clic sur les bouttons
  function slideLi(arg) {
    var btnClick = document.getElementById('btn-' + arg);
    btnClick.onclick = function() {
      wrapper.style.marginLeft = -arg * slideWidth + "px";
      slideActif();
    }
  }

  // Ajoute la classe 'actif' uniquement à l'élément sur lequel on clic
  function slideActif() {
    var slidePosition = -Number(wrapper.style.marginLeft.replace("px", "")) / slideWidth;
    //console.log(slidePosition);
    var btnClick = document.getElementById('btn-' + slidePosition);
    var slideBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-slide");
    for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
      slideBtn[i].classList.remove("actif"); // J'enlève la classe 'actif' aux autres
    }
    btnClick.classList.add("actif"); // J'attribue la classe 'actif' au li sur lequel je clic
  }


  // On crée une variable intervalSlider qui lancera la fonction slideNext toutes les 3000ms (slideDelay)
  // Fonction pour arrêter le slider et une pour le démarrer
  var intervalSlider = setInterval(slideNext, slideDelay);

  function sliderStop() {
    clearInterval(intervalSlider);
  }

  function sliderPlay() {
    intervalSlider = setInterval(slideNext, slideDelay);
  }

  slider.onmouseover = function() {
    sliderStop();
  }

  slider.onmouseout = function() {
    sliderPlay();
  }

  // Utiliser les flèches
  document.onkeydown = touche;

  function touche(event) {
    var touche = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (touche == 37) {
      slidePrevious();
    } else if (touche == 39) {
      slideNext();
    }
  }

  slideActif();
}
```

```css
.slider-container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: white;
}

#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slide {
  float: left;
}

.slide img {
  display: block;
}

#wrapper {
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}

#next-button {
  background: url(../images/slider/next.png) no-repeat center, rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
}

#previous-button {
  background: url(../images/slider/prev.png) no-repeat center, rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
}

#next-button:hover {
  background: url(../images/slider/next.png) no-repeat center, rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.4);
}

#previous-button:hover {
  background: url(../images/slider/prev.png) no-repeat center, rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.4);
}

#group-btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-slide {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.actif {
  border: 2px solid #00add9;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="slide">
        <p><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Nuages"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <p><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Dessin japonais"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <p><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Combat VS"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <p><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Aquarium"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please replace the php code with generated code, this way we can create a working example to debug the issue. It doesn't need to be full code, just something to make this work

Comment: Php code replaced with plain html !

Comment: Looks like the slide works, width and height are as defined. I don't see next/prev buttons. I commented out the console log as it was polluting the result when code is ran. Also reduced the length of the slides to 4 as we don't need anymore to debug this

Comment: As I also manage to get it work an a blank web page, could it be my issue if the `.slider-container' is in a jquery toggle() ? Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell by that screenshot, maybe attach more code to reproduce the issue you are actually experiencing

Comment: It is not actually, but here is the full generated code : https://codeshare.io/5RMeDB

Comment: Looks like there are some invalid html in your code. For example, a `p` tag cannot contain more `p` tags, you can change you outer `p` tag to a div.